# Why CSS float left can't put two divs on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I want to make two divs on the same line with CSS.

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
#login_left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}
#login_right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">this is the top
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="login_left">login_left
    </div>
    <div id="login_right">login_right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">this is the footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Both login_left and login_right are all set float:left in the css and width is 50%,why can't make the two login_left and login_right be put on the same line?

What i get for my css in firefox is the following.

1. Why the blue div is full of 900 px?
2. Why the yellow div is not be set on the right?

[image]

Comment: You are adding a border to something that is already 50%. The overall width will be more that 50%, which wont fit on one 100% row.

Comment: are you sure that's the login-left div and not the #main div? can you show us your html?

Comment: box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: also, flexbox is a great solution for this

Comment: Div's have display 'block' by default, change that to 'inline' or 'inline-block'. That should help

Comment: If you don't want to use flex or border-box. Try adding your border to a div inside the main structural divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
body{
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;}
div{
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;}
#wrapper{
    width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;}
#main{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;}
#login_left{
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    }   
#login_right{
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    } 
#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:white;
    display:table;
    } 
</style>
</header>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">this is the top
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="login_left">login_left
        </div>
        <div id="login_right" >login_right
        </div>       
    </div>
    <div id="footer">this is the footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additions to your code:
`box-sizing:border-box;` to the div selector. Think of this as an internal border instead of an external one. It doesn't add any overall size to your elements using this attribute. As you were using 50% and 50%, adding 1px to all sides means you're over 100%, making your divs stack.

`display:table;` to the footer to make it display in a table layout and respect your border size to match the other tables.

Comment: Can you explain why this answers the OP?

Comment: Sure, just added the explanation to the new elements

Answer (score 8):

1. You use border so divs are 50% + 2px (to fix that use `box-sizing: border-box;` )
2. login_left is 50% (+2px) wide, the fact that all the line is blue is because #main has a blue background

Answer (score 2):

```
div {
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2qvrunmn/1/)

The problem is with the border. It is using extra 2 px.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the borders makes it work:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/jh6tsw0c/)

```
div{
    font-size:30px;
}
```

If you want to keep them followinf the other answers:

```
div{
   box-sizing:border-box; //ADD THIS
   border:1px solid black;
   font-size:30px;
}
```